# How to add Timer in rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have created an application in rails.In that i have a Quiz Module.Quiz is working fine but i wants a Timer in this Module.How do i add a Timer for 5 minutes for whole quiz which will be showing like this- > 05:00 to 00:00  ?

Comment: For submission validation you simply need to keep track of quiz start time and submission time. For display in your front end you 'll need to use a js plugin.

Comment: check this JS library http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [**`countdown gem`**](https://github.com/jnbt/countdown)

I hope this will helps you.. :)